# Following CSV file script are not working properly in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I used following script in my rout file.

```
Route::get('/tasks', 'appointmentController@exportCsv')
```

I used the following Js script Html Clickable button in blade template

```
<script>
   function exportTasks(_this) {
      let _url = $(_this).data('href');
      window.location.href = _url;
   }
</script>

<span data-href="./tasks" id="export" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="exportTasks(event.target);">Export Client Email</span>
```

I used the following script in my controller. I cant find where is the script problem. CSV file are not download include with the data.

```
public function exportCsv(Request $request)
     {
       

   $fileName = 'tasks.csv';
   $tasks = Clientinformation::all();

        $headers = array(
            "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
            "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires"             => "0"
        );

        $columns = array('customerName', 'email', 'cell1', 'cell2', 'landNumber');

        $callback = function() use($tasks, $columns) {
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($file, $columns);

            foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                $row['customerName']  = $task->customerName;
                $row['email']    = $task->assign->email;
                $row['cell1']    = $task->cell1;
                $row['cell2']  = $task->cell2;
                $row['landNumber']  = $task->landNumber;

fputcsv($file, array($row['customerName'], $row['email'], $row['cell1'], $row['cell2'], $row['cell2'], $row['landNumber'] ));
            }

            fclose($file);
        };

        return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);
     }
```

Comment: All good with the script. What do you get in your browser, when you open the page `http://<your_site>/tasks`? It might be that your `$task` does not have a needed `assign`, so it breaks in the line `$task->assign->email`

Comment: i dont get anything while i click the button. really i cant understand where is my problem.

Comment: Not enough info to tell where the culprit is. Try looking in `laravel.log` file, or if that doesn't help, monitor the logs of your web-server